# $\sum a_nz^n, \sum b_nz^n,$ and $\sum a_nb_nz^n$ having $R =1$, $\implies$ $\sum a_nb_n^2z^n$ and $\sum a_n^2b_nz^n$ also have $R=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Show that if each of the series $\sum a_nz^n, \sum b_nz^n,$ and $\sum a_nb_nz^n$ has radius of convergence $R =1$, then show the series $\sum a_nb_n^2z^n$ and $\sum a_n^2b_nz^n$ also have radius of convergence $R=1.$

First we start with the definition:

\begin{split}
1/R=1 & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}  \\
 & = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|a_nb_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}
\end{split}

Now we attempt to show $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|a_nb_n^2|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(|b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2= 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|a_n^2b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\left(|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2b_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$$

Certainly, one would like to simply substitute algebraically our assumed radii of convergence, but this is incorrect given we don't know the limits exist themselves, only their $\lim\sup.$

It was suggested one use the following subsequence argument constructed from the $\lim\sup $ assumption that I don't really understand:

Since $1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup|a_nb_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$, there exists a sequence $n_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}|b_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}=1$. We also have $\lim\sup|a_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}\leq1$ and $\lim\sup|a_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}\leq1$... one uses these claims to derive that the limits indeed exist as a result of $\lim_{k\to\infty} |a_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}|b_{n_k}|^{\frac{1}{n_k}}=1$ having a convergent subsequence.

Can anyone walk me carefully through this logic and how one might rigorously conclude:

$\lim\sup|a_nb_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\implies\lim|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim|b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1\implies$

$\lim\sup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\left(|b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2=\left(\lim\sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)\left(\lim\sup|b_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |b_n|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n b_n|^{1/n} = 1 \, .
$$
and the goal is to show that $S = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |a_n b_n^2|^{1/n}$ is equal to one.

From
$$
 |a_n b_n^2|^{1/n} = |a_n|^{1/n} \cdot \left( |b_n|^{1/n} \right)^2
$$
one can conclude that $S  \le 1 \cdot 1^2 = 1$. On the other hand,
$$
 \left(|a_n b_n|^{1/n}\right)^2 = |a_n |^{1/n} \cdot |a_n b_n^2|^{1/n}
$$
implies $1^2 \le 1 \cdot S$ and therefore $S \ge 1$.

---

Both estimates use that
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n y_n \le \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty} y_n
$$
and
$$
 \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n^2 = \left(\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n \right)^2
$$
for non-negative real sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.